# postgresql: dblink inserting on remote database

Tags: postgresql, triggers, dblink

This is my situation,

I have two databases (*db1*, *db2*), both with table "countries". I need that when I insert on *db1*.countries, automatically inserts on *db2*.countries. I'm using **dblink** module to connect with the second database.

countries table SQL schema is:

```
CREATE TABLE countries (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  flag VARCHAR(5) 
);
```

To manage this situation, on *db1* I have created the following procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION prc_insert_to_countries()
      RETURNS trigger AS
    $$
    DECLARE 
        insert_statement TEXT;
        res TEXT;
    BEGIN                
        perform dblink_connect('db2', 'dbname=db2 host=localhost 
        user=xxx password=xxx');

        insert_statement = 'insert into countries(id, name, flag) 
                                    values ('||NEW.id||', 
                                    '''||NEW.name||''', 
                                    '''||NEW.flag||'''
                                    );';
        res := dblink_exec('db2', insert_statement, true);
        RAISE INFO '%', res;
        perform dblink_disconnect('db2');
        RETURN NEW;
    END;
    $$
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

And the following trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_countries
      AFTER INSERT
      ON countries
      FOR EACH ROW
      EXECUTE PROCEDURE prc_insert_to_countries();
```

If I execute the next insert statement on *db1*:

```
INSERT INTO countries (id, name, flag) VALUES (1, 'Italy', 'ITA');
```

All works perfectly, and the inserted row is inserted into *db2*.countries too.
But if I execute:

```
INSERT INTO countries (id, name, flag) VALUES (1, 'Italy', NULL);
```

The inserted row is not inserted into *db2*.countries...

I have tried to solve this with this post: [postgresql trigger with dblink doesn't return anything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35296562/postgresql-trigger-with-dblink-doesnt-return-anything) but it doesnt' works me..

How can I solve this?

Thanks.

Comment: That's probably because concatenating (`||`) with `NULL` results in `NULL` (your `insert_statement` will be `NULL`). Also, concatenating SQL statements opens up the possibility for SQL injection. Use the [`format()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-FORMAT) function instead of concatenating manually.

Comment: or quote_nullable

Comment: Using format() function works perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The NULL field yields the problem, try to use COALESCE to handle the NULL like this:

```
insert_statement = 'insert into countries(id, name, flag) 
                                    values ('||NEW.id||', 
                                    '''||NEW.name||''', 
                                    '''||COALESCE(NEW.flag,'')||'''
                                    );';
```

Just keep in mind that the flag field in the remote db will get an empty string isntead of NULL.